# Questions with deleted profiles

Tags: discussion

What should be the outcome of questions with deleted profiles? It's a guarantee that we won't be getting any reputation from that person, and seems useless to try to answer a question for someone that has no profile.

Example: 
[SharePoint 2007: what happens to hyperlinks when moving a subsite?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57525/sharepoint-2007-what-happens-to-hyperlinks-when-moving-a-subsite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might still get rep. from up votes, but clearly no chance of accepted answer.

I think if the user doesn't exist any more and there are no answers after a while we might as well delete the question as a dead loss.